# In hybris cmscockpit the custom components are not recognised for synchronization

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

Knowing the workaround for synchronization, of custom `parent-child components`, I included my custom types in `customcockpit-spring-services.xml`.

However, this did not work.
Whereas when I add same custom types to OOTB `cmscockpit-spring-services.xml`, it works like charm.

My bean definition:

```
<alias alias="synchronizationService" name="customSynchronizationService" />
<bean id="customSynchronizationService" class="de.hybris.platform.cmscockpit.sync.CMSSynchronizationService" scope="tenant" autowire="byName">
  <property name="relatedReferencesTypesMap">
    <entry key="AbstractPage">
      <list>
        .....
        <value>SampleCampaignComponent.campaigns</value>
        <value>SampleCampaignItem</value>
        <value>SimpleCMSComponent</value>
      </list>
    </entry>
  </property>
  <property name="searchRestrictionsDisabled" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Any suggestions on this customization?

Comment: I improved the code formatting and some highlighting.

Comment: Thanks:) @zx485  Hope some one can help me:)

Comment: Did I understand you correct, that in works when you add it to the 'cmscockpit-spring-services.xml' but not when you add it to the 'customcockpit-spring-services.xml' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @KilleKat and @Shreshtt Bhatt for your response.
I found it working after I commented the custom bean defined in `cmscockpit-services.xml` of `yacceleratorcockpits` extension.

From which I understand that, if we have accelerator extension better to extend the accelerator template rather using ycockpit template.

Answer (score 0):

If it didn't worked, you can copy paste whole bean definition as it is in your customcockpit-spring-services.xml and add additional component (like what you did in OOTB xml). This should fixed the issue.

```
<alias alias="synchronizationService" name="defaultCMSSynchronizationService" />
<alias alias="defaultSynchronizationService" name="defaultCMSSynchronizationService" />
<bean id="defaultCMSSynchronizationService" class="de.hybris.platform.cmscockpit.sync.CMSSynchronizationService" scope="tenant" autowire="byName">
    <property name="relatedReferencesTypesMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="AbstractCMSComponent">
                <list>
                   <value>SampleCampaignComponent.campaigns</value>
                   ......
                </list>
             </entry>
             ...........
         </map>
    </property>
    <property name="searchRestrictionsDisabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

If you really don't want to rewrite bean definition as a whole, then you can check with `merge="true"`

```
<alias alias="synchronizationService" name="customSynchronizationService" />
<bean id="customSynchronizationService"
    class="de.hybris.platform.cmscockpit.sync.CMSSynchronizationService" parent="defaultSynchronizationService">
    <property name="relatedReferencesTypesMap">
        <map merge="true">
            <entry key="AbstractCMSComponent">
                <list merge="true">
                    <value>SampleCampaignComponent.campaigns</value>
                </list>
            </entry>                
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```